# Ubuntu 20.04 switch to multi version of PHP returns error 500 on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed multiple version of PHP 5.6, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 and 8.0 with 7.4 set as the default. I tried to switch to different version for some projects running on older version, doing this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Then restart the apache by doing:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And also did if switching to other version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Then restarted Apache

But when I open to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` again which was working recently, now its throwing error 500 then did check the error on `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and it says:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 23\nPHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/Loader.php on line 116\n`

And created a file with `phpinfo` it it and printed the PHP version, it says php 5.6 but in CLI, by doing `php -v` it says php 7.4, below is the screenshot of the `phpinfo()`

[image]

Any help, ideas, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Just enable PHP 7.1 + for `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` by making `.htaccess` file in that folder with content like:

```
<FilesMatch \.php> 
    # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket 
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/" 
</FilesMatch>
```

or change PHP version from `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

You can also try updating phpmyadmin to latest version (4.9.7 is latest version supporting PHP 5.5+ currently, and Ubuntu 4.9.5 installs older version by default currently)